# Understanding Calculate Measure with variables

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I have calculated the next measure that provides the TOTALYTD in the previous year:

[image]

It is working as expected. For dates before 01/07/2006, I do not have any value in my second table. However, if I change the formula using a variable, I'm getting this result:

[image]

The calculation is performed in the same year (2006). I have been trying to understand the **context** (kind of new with Dax), but I have not understood this result yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you store a calculation in a variable, it becomes a constant, and can't be re-calculated. That's why DATEDD in your second measure has no effect.

As a good practice, break your calculations into multiple measures. It allows you to re-use them, and makes your code more readable and maintainable. For example:

```
Sales Amount = SUM(InternetSales[SalesAmount])

Sales YTD = TOTALYTD( [Sales Amount], Calendario[Date])

Sales YTD LY = CALCULATE( [Sales YTD], PREVIOUSYEAR( Calendario[Date]))
```

Comment: Hi @RADO. Thanks for your replay and advice. So,  just to have everything more clear, in this case is when we talk about **Row Context**?

Comment: No, Row Context has nothing to do with this. This is about filter context. Every DAX formula is executed within a set of filters that are active for it (slicers, matrix rows and columns, etc). Function CALCULATE can be used to modify filter context (to override or supplement filters). However, when you store DAX calculation results in a variable, it's too late - it's already executed and converted into a constant. Constant can't be affected by changes in the filters (it's just a fixed number). So, if you use CALCULATE on a variable, nothing happens.